# Serialize inner class with GSON in JAVA

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, inner-classes

I want to serialize a class which contains an inner class with GSON. I have already checked it is important the inner class be static. I have made it static, but my code does not serialize it.

The class I want to serialize:

```
public class A{

    static class B{
        public String b; 

        public B() {}
    }

    private int data1 = 100;
    private String data2 = "hello";
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
      {
        add("String 1");
        add("String 2");
        add("String 3");
      }
    };

    public A(){

    }
}
```

The code which make the seralization:

```
public class json 
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            A a = new A();
            String j = gson.toJson(t);

            System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

The result:

```
{"data1":100,"data2":"hello","list":["String 1","String 2","String 3"]}
```

The problem is that the result does not contain the inner class serialization.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a field of type `B` inside `A` so there's nothing to serialize.

You'd need something like ...

```
public class A {
    ...
    private B b;
    ...
    public A() {
        b = new B();
        b.b = "Some String";
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the suitable [link](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Nested-Classes-including-Inner-Classes-) . It defines the way to do this but making the inner class as static is the recommended option.

Answer (score 1):

Since your B class does not have any values it is not serialized.
To serialize that,

You may configure the gson builder with:

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls();
 Gson gson=gsonBuilder.create();
 gson.toJson(a);
```

Here is the link:
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#null-object-support